# FFMPEG - moov atom not found after elaboration

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a command where I put overlay images over a video. 
After that I resize the output to fit certain dimensions.

Everything usually works fine, but sometimes and only from a certain desktop computer, when the second elaboration starts, the command returns an error: `moov atom not found`

Lets put some code:

My first command is pretty long, I past just the important stuff with a 2 pictures example:

```
-i inputVideo.mp4 -i 1.jpg -i 2.jpg
-filter_complex "[1:v]format=yuva422p,[Other effects...][im1];
[2:v]format=yuva422p,[Other effects...][im2];
[0][im1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h)/2[o1];
[o1][im2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h)/2"
-crf 18 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

My second command is the following:

```
-i output.mp4 -crf 19 resized.mp4
```

I think I am missing something in my first command, but what?
If I execute the same exact code from my portable computer, it works fine.

Thanks for the help!

Here is the link for both log [ffmpeg logs](https://github.com/Shinitorix/FFMPEG_Log)

### Last edit (I hope) :)

I added in that github repository the ffmpeg command I tried and the source files to reproduce the problem. I hope anyone will ever find a solution

In the repository there are:

- *LAST_CommandLine_Command* -> it's the ffmpeg command I am running
- *LAST_CommandLine_Command_Output* -> it is one of my ffmpeg's run output (it's the last I've tried)
- Files from *01.jpg* to *10.jpg* -> those are the pictures I'm overlaying over the video with the command
- [My input video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CbWxLy7VHnkJAwfIqQy8MzdLmEjOZt5B) for the ffmpeg command.

I tried running this command with:
- A Windows console application that run it for me
- Directly from command line
- With a command line dotnet myapplication.dll (running my application not from debug but from publish)

Results:

It worked 1 times out of 10 for those specific files, in other cases it randomly stopped after some seconds (fron 45'' to 1'55'', depending on run).

Note: I tried with `-threads 1`, `-threads 2` and without any thread limitation. It failed in all cases

Comment: Why re-encode `output.mp4` which introduces generational quality loss instead of re-sizing in the original command?

Comment: Need to see log for file creation method

Comment: @llogan I did it because I needed to resize the video to a certain Mb dimension, and I didn't find any "one line" command to do it, so I tried to recursively scale the video until it fit the desired dimension.. is there a faster way to achieve it?

Comment: Log file is truncated.

Comment: @Gyan the missing lines are only the frame elaboration ones; I removed them because the answer would have been to long. I will add some line in the top and some in the end, but I can't add them all

Comment: Paste the full log elsewhere and share a link.

Comment: @Gyan done, good idea

Comment: If that's the full log, it indicates that ffmpeg got stuck and never flushed the header to disk. Your build is almost a year old - upgrade and check.

Comment: @Gyan you are totally right! checking some of those elaborations are stopping before the end of the process. I noticed that this appens only if the video is > 2min and with > than 6 pictures in overlay. Newer FFMPEG versions doesn't fix it. Any idea about what it could be? I'm running ffmpeg through C# code

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley If you run the same ffmpeg command manually, unscripted in a command-line interface does it also fail? Not sure what you mean by "Mb dimension".

Comment: @llogan I tried and unfortunatly I got the same problem; elaboration ends before the end of the process. I added in my Github repo the exact code I used for this specific elaboration. (With "Mb dimension" I meant that I want my video to be smaller than a certain megabyte dimension, in this case for example 30Mb)

Comment: @llogan after some more tries, I found out that the code, run by command line, works 50% of the times.. awkard..

Comment: I think (but i'm not an expert) that the problem might be my processor who cannot afford a too complex operation. I added an overlayed text and it fails 80% of times now (by suddently stopping elaboration)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley Maybe the CPU is overheating, but I don't know. The logs are not showing anything obviously wrong. Try with `nice ffmpeg -i input ... -threads 1 output` and see if it works.

Comment: @llogan it still breaks.. awkard

Comment: @llogan I tried a bounch of new stuffs but anything work.. sometimes, randomly, my cmd process stops without any exit error code. Is there any way for me to check if the output is correctly encoded or if the operation is succesfully finished from ffmpeg? I would avoid to save a wrongly formatted video if possible

Comment: Does it fail on another computer?

Comment: @llogan unfortunatly, on another computer it didn't fail yet.. but on that computer if I run my application from "debug" mode instead of published one, looks like it works

Comment: Did you ever upgrade your ffmpeg as suggested earlier? Can you verify that the ffmpeg command outputs a bad file when you run the command manually in a command line interface (not via your c# code)?

Comment: @llogan yes ffmpeg is now updated as suggested; the next time it fails I will try to execute my command from cmd directly and let you know how it goes! thanks a lot

Comment: @llogan Ok.. I finally tried running a command from my application (both debug and release mode) and from command line. In all cases it failed, statistic: 1 successful run out of 10 tries. I edited my question with the required informations and I added all informations to reproduce that specific case in the gitHub repository + drive link. If you have any idea about whi it is failing, it would be really appreciated. Thanks for your time

Comment: @llogan Ok, now I have a couple of months of testings and I can confirm that it was a computer-related problem. I formatted my computer and now it's been working for 2 months like a charme without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of struggling on that problem, I found out that it was a problem related to my windows version and/or installation.

I formatted my computer, installed a clean new version of windows 10 and now it works like charm.

Thanks all for the support.

PS: I hate windows ^.^